# Spinner not showing selected item or default item but dropdown list works

Tags: android, spinner

android spinner is empty by default or when items selected. I tried using the default layout for spinner but still empty. I have checked every question on this website but none helped.

Here is the code:

spinner view on activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"

        >

        </Spinner>


</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class ShowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<String> list;
Spinner dropdown;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

    TextView titleView = findViewById(R.id.showTitle);
    String title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
    titleView.setText(title);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    dropdown = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(title).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    list.add(document.getId());
                }
                Log.d("Success ", list.toString());
            } else {
                Log.d("Failed ", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ShowActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_items, list);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_items);

    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

spinner_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTV"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
/>
```

thank you in advance.
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"` should be `wrap_content`

Comment: That changes the width of the textview on drop down list but the text still doesn't appear when selected.

Comment: did you change the height as well? I would have to see more of your code to be able to help

Comment: @Emmanuel i have updated the question does this help now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(title).get().addOnCompleteListener(...)` is an asynchronous call. Your code will continue to execute here:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ShowActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_items, list);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_items);

    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

At this time the list is still empty. You need to move this block inside of the `OnCompleteListener`.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

After  dropdown.setAdapter(adapter); you have to set up item select/clicked listener, try this:

```
dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//.. do stuff here
   }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
 // do default when nothing is selected
            }
        });
dropdown.setSelection(0) // this makes default selection for dropdown item....
```

Hope I could help you, best regards, 
Csongi

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for to add next.